# A linked list in another class accessible from one method but not from another

Tags: java, model-view-controller, iterator, linked-list, paint

Ok I'm really not understanding why this isn't working.

```
class SketcherModel extends Observable implements Iterable<Element>{

    public Iterator<Element> iterator(){
        return elements.iterator();
    }   

    public LinkedList<Element> elements = new LinkedList<Element>();
}
```

So I have a LinkedList in the class `Element` in the 'model' portion of my application. The idea is that when the 'view' portion of the app executes the `paint()` method it'll access the linked list and draw each `Element` it contains, as shown in the code below:

```
public class SketcherView extends JComponent implements Observer{
    public SketcherView(Sketcher theApp){
        this.theApp = theApp;

        //Testing to see if I can access the linked list, 'elements', outside of the paint() method;
        Element test = theApp.getModel().elements.iterator().next() 
    }

    public void update(Observable o, Object rectangle){
        //Code to respond to changes in model...
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D)g;
        for(Element element : theApp.getModel()){
            element = (Element)elements.iterator().next();
            g2D.setPaint(element.getColor());
            g2D.draw(element.getShape());
        }    
    }
```

Now when accessing the linked list `elements` from the class constructor it seems to find it with no problems , however when I used the collection-based for loop to run through `elements` using the iterator it says 'elements cannot be resolved'. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D)g;
    for(Element element : theApp.getModel()){
        element = (Element)elements.iterator().next();
        g2D.setPaint(element.getColor());
        g2D.draw(element.getShape());
    } 
}
```

You don't have any `elements` variable in the method. And the current element of the loop is already declared in the for loop. The code should be

```
for(Element element : theApp.getModel()){
    g2D.setPaint(element.getColor());
    g2D.draw(element.getShape());
}
```

Another, unrealated problem, is that you should override `paintComponent()`, and not `paint()`.

Comment: Thanks for shedding light to the problem, but even if I try and access `elements` through the instant of the 'model' saved in `element` should I not have access? (I want to know why it doesn't work so I don't make the same mistake again)

Also when is using `paint()` instead of `paintComponent()` ever needed?

Comment: Since `elements` is a public field of the model, you could write the loop as `for (Element element : theApp.getModel().elements)`, or as `List<Element> elements = theApp.getModel().elements; for (Element element : elements)`. AFAIK, `paint()` should never be overridden by Swing components.